# How to use vi as a full featured programming editor

Tags: linux, vim

I have seen people being able to use `vi` for programming purposes and being able to see e.g. the methods a file contains, jump from a method invocation to its definition etc. I.e. being able to use it a full featured programming editor.
How can I do this? Do I need some special plugins? Is there an easy guide for setting this up?

Comment: You have probably seen VIM do this....

Comment: @mdpc:In my mind `vi` and `vim` are the same (perhaps erroneously).So how do they do this?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use vim to programming here are some useful plugins (and other):

- [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) or similar to generate list of your functions, variables,...
- [vim-taglist](http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/) to show your functions, variables,...
- [vim-taboo](https://github.com/gcmt/taboo.vim) to manage your tabs
- [vim-sqlutilities](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=492) if you want to format your sql-queries
- [omni-completion](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Omni_completion_popup_menu)
- your preferred language-specific vim-plugins
- etc, etc, etc.

Comment: I am sorry for the lamen question, but how do I install the plugin?

Comment: Completely depends on the environment.  Some distributions include various plugins in the package repository.  If they own, then you'll have to download and for the install the plugins.  Each plugin will probably include a README/INSTALL file with instructions.  Read those.

Comment: @Zoredache:When you say plugin you mean an `rpm` right?

Comment: No I didn't.  I mean plugin as in VIM plugin.  I also wouldn't have meant RPM, since I am very much a Debian/Ubuntu person, which uses .deb as the format for files in the package repository.  Not that it matters, my comment was meant to be generic.  Start by searching for packages built into to your distro.   If they are not present, then you have to build and install them yourself.

Comment: If you haven't got package from these plugins, you'll download and (generally) should copy `~/.vim/plugins` or `~/.vim/ftplugins`.

Answer (score 4):

You most likely don't have `vi` on your system. Most Linux distributions use Vim instead and link the `vi` command to Vim which is an improved version of `vi` that tries to stay compatible with it. In the future, try to write "Vim" (or "VIM" or however you want to capitalize it) when you don't specifically ask something about the old and dead `vi` that nobody uses anymore (Yes, I know someone will downvote this answer and comment that he uses vi…).

The default Vim is often a "tiny" version that lacks useful features like clipboard, multibyte or Ruby/Python support, for example. Use your distribution's package manager to make it more useful by installing `vim-gtk` or `vim-gnome`.

If you need a plugin or a colorscheme, the best place to look at is [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/scripts/index.php). If you are working with a specific language, you can try to google `vim $language ide`: there are many tutorials.

- **"see the methods a file contains"**

  You are probably thinking about [TagList](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=273) or [TagBar](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3465). Both plugins use an external program called [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) (there are a bunch of language-specific alternatives) to generate an index of your code.
- **"jump from a method invocation to its definition"**

  This is typically done by pressing `<C-]>` with the cursor on the method name and depends on a `tags` file generated by ctags against your code. See `:help tags` and `:help ctags`.

  If the definition is in the same file, you can use `gd` which has no dependency.

If you are genuinely curious about Vim, I'd suggest you try to learn to use it with as few plugins as possible: you can do a lot with bare Vim and no plugin as it comes with syntax highlighting, indentation rules, completion and specific settings for dozens of languages and many other useful features.

One *very important* thing to keep in mind, though, is that **Vim is not an IDE**. It doesn't have an internal parser that scans your code in real time to report syntax error or perform smart refactoring. Vim is a *text editor* geared toward programmers: it doesn't understand your code *at all* but it offers the kind of unparalleled text editing features that programmers like.

You can install many plugins and think you have an IDE but *you don't*. Keep that in mind.

Finally, here are the two lines you *need* to put in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
```

The 1st one activates language detection and language-specific settings, indenting and so on.

The 2nd one activates syntax highlighting.

Suggested reading:

```
:help quickref
:help usr_01 and following
:help windows
:help motion (my favorite)
```

Comment: +1. Very helpful.`The 1st one activates language detection and language-specific settings`. You mean programming language or locale?

Comment: Programming language of course.

Comment: So the idea is that  I run ctag over the code base and *then* I use `vi` on the source code

Comment: No, you use Vim. And what you do over the code base depends on what outcome you want. If you want to be able to "jump to definition" and back you must generate a `tags` file and make sure it is somewhere Vim can find it (`:h ctags`) before you can use one of the commands/shortcuts listed in `:h tags`.

Comment: -1 I still use `vi`

Comment: I *knew* it... ;-)